# How to insert a '1' at the end of an xml node in a varchar2 field in plsql?

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to insert a '1' at the end of the `referenceid` node in a varchar2 field that contains xml data.  I am having a hard time understanding if that is possible. Here is an example of the field data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><RECEIVE_PO_005><CNTROLAREA><BSR><VERB>RECEIVE</VERB>
<NOUN>PO</NOUN><REVISION>005</REVISION></BSR><SENDER><LOGICALID>2</LOGICALID>
<COMPONENT>-</COMPONENT><TASK>RECEIVEPO</TASK>
<REFERENCEID>20241920x32255420001-0047x4210743</REFERENCEID>....................
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [an Oracle built-in function, `UPDATEXML()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm) which will allow you to do this. Because you want to append to the existing attribute rather than overwriting it there's an additional bit of pfaffing with `extract()` to get the text value:

```
update x23 
set xmlt =
   UPDATEXML(xmlt, '/RECEIVE_PO_005/CNTROLAREA/SENDER/REFERENCEID/text()',
     extract(xmlt, '/RECEIVE_PO_005/CNTROLAREA/SENDER/REFERENCEID/text()')||'-1')
where id = 1;
```

Concatenated `-1` just to make it easier to spot :)

The paths may not be right for you: I had to guess what your whole document looked like [for the LiveSQL demo (free OTN account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gbk2y0r42srykx8c3sieufpch).

---

I notice your question says you are storing the XML in a `varchar2` column not as an `xmltype`. It's a very good idea to use the Oracle XMLType column to store XML because it provides all sorts of neat functionality. Like `UPDATEXML()`, which does not work with a plain string. To make it work with a `varchar2` column you need to cast the column to `xmltype`, like this:

```
update x23 
set xmlt =
   UPDATEXML(xmlType(xmlt), '/RECEIVE_PO_005/CNTROLAREA/SENDER/REFERENCEID/text()',
     extract(xmlType(xmlt), '/RECEIVE_PO_005/CNTROLAREA/SENDER/REFERENCEID/text()') || '-1')
where id = 1;
```

Comment: @jck7282008 - if you have found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.